# Accessing key vault - sas token - azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-keyvault

Within Azure DevOps, my pipeline emits the error:

`##[error]Get secrets failed. Error: Could not fetch access token for Azure. Verify if the Service Principal used is valid and not expired..`

I am fetching other values, without fault from key vault and verified my service principal has the right permissions to read from key vault as that is where the sas token is deployed.

In fact the service principal is dynamically created via terraform and has no set expiration so that ruiles out that root cause.

I checked within Azure Key Vault and showed the sas-token secret to verify it is being pulled correctly.

The code block within my azurepipeline YAML file, reads the token as an environment variable:

```
  # Init
    - task: TerraformCLI@0
      displayName: Initialize Terraform
      env:
      # using interpolation to reference sas secret environment variable being pulled from the key vault
        ARM_SAS_TOKEN: $(sas_token)
      inputs:
        command: init
        # workind directory points to the context within which the command above is ran 
        workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ned-cloud-tutorial/vnet
        # configuring the backend, sotrage account, container name and key. 
        
        commandOptions: -backend-config=storage_account_name=$(storageaccount) -backend-config=container_name=$(container_name) -backend-config=key=$(key)
        backendType: selfConfigured
```

I am more than happy to share more code if additional informaiton is needed as this is a very particular question and I have had no luck on stackoverflow and general google queries. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you checked with the `backendType` setting to `azurerm`? [Authenticating using a Service Principal with a Client Secret](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret)

Comment: Hi zimcanit, what's the latest status of this issue?

Comment: Hi @CeenoQi-MSFT thanks for checking. I ensured the backend type is correct and the scope of permissions assigned to my service principal are adequate for use to access the token. However, the fault remains.